# BIRT Data set consisting of report parameters

Tags: parameters, dataset, birt

I am rather new to BIRT and reporting, and thus I am not sure whether there is an easy answer to this question but I have yet to find one.

I have some 10 parameters I want to use to consist of the data within a data set, but I am unsure as to how to approach this.

The idea is that the user enters a list of names and numbers through the parameters, for which the numbers query xml data. Then, the xml data is grouped within a chart and table according to the names passed.

I could group the data if the names consisted of a data set, but they are separate parameters.

I had an image below, but as I am new to the community as well I do not have enough reputation to post this, unfortunately. The idea is to create a report comparing total electrical consumption comparing different electrical meters, with their names drawn from parameters and xml data consisting of values and timestamps. From my understanding, the best way to approach this is to create a data set consisting of parameters, but I am unsure how to do this. Any advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: It is possible to use a "scripted dataset" to convert report parameters into a dataset as we like. With 10 parameters, you mean there are 5 parameters representing meter names and 5 parameters for number values?

Comment: Sorry, I meant 10 name parameters. 20 in total.

Right now I've attempted to create a global array, draw bindings from the queried xml data set, and then attempted to pass the parameters into a scripted data set over top of the array. However, right now I'm having difficulty in the locations for where to place the scripts.

I've declared the global variables in the initialize script on the  under the overall report.
Under onFetch of the queried data set, I've tried to create binding to the arrays by passing rows to the global array.
From there, I have the global array create columns in the...

Comment: ... fetch of the scripted data set. Do you know if that is the correct choice of script locations?

Comment: It should work, if you ensure the xml dataset is running before the scripted dataset in the report body. Though if i understood correctly you should probably use a joined dataset instead of a global array

Comment: @dom Thank-you for your response. 

I've got a grassroots version working, where I can pass values into columns. However, it's encountering difficulty when I try and pass values from a computed column from a data set into a global array. The code works when I pass a queried column into the array, but passes no data (nor returns an error) when I change the column passed to the computed one. Do you have any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: Just for the newbies like me, I solved my original question by posting this code into the fetch script of a scripted data set. The parameters consist of M1 Name, M2 Name, etc.

Open:
`jk = 0;`

fetch:
`row["MeterNames"] = params["M" +(jk+1)+ " Name"].value;
jk++;`
`